# Remove template drop down for certain pages

Tags: customization, templates

I have a number of custom templates which are assigned to different pages in my admin.

Is it possible to hide/lock the templates dropdown for certain pages? For instance, I have an `Events Calendar` template which will only ever be assigned to the Events Calendar page and so there is no need for the client to see this in the dropdown box however it should still be accessible for admins.

Thanks for help or guidance.

Answer (score 1):

### The "How?"

To get rid of a meta box, you got several hooks straight after they were added inside `~/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php`. The one you need it `'dbx_post_advanced'`. The you just need to remove the meta box with [`remove_meta_box()`](http://queryposts.com/function/remove_meta_box/).

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;
/** Plugin Name: (#90253) Remove Page Template Drop Down */
add_action( 'dbx_post_advanced', 'wpse90235_remove_page_template_metabox' );
function wpse90235_remove_page_template_metabox()
{
    remove_meta_box( 'pageparentdiv', null, 'side' );
}
```

That's the only chance doing it.

### They "Why?"

The `page_attributes_meta_box()` callback that builds the meta box uses `wp_dropdown_pages()` and runs the arguments through a filter called `'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args'` which has two arguments: `$dropdown_args` and `$post`. When look at the arguments, you'll see that there's the `echo` argument set to `0/false`, which *shouldn't* output anything.

```
$dropdown_args = array(
    'post_type'        => $post->post_type,
    'exclude_tree'     => $post->ID,
    'selected'         => $post->post_parent,
    'name'             => 'parent_id',
    'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'),
    'sort_column'      => 'menu_order, post_title',
    'echo'             => 0,
);
```

...Sadly the `echo` is forced right after that:

```
<?php echo $pages; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider: if you name the template file `page-{$page_slug}.php` or `page-{$ID}.php` (matching the page in the admin interface/area/backend) then it will load that template without it being a 'page template' in the dropdown.

See the [Template Hierarchy Diagram](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) in the Codex.

Comment: You're talking about the template hierarchy?

Comment: yes I am. depending on whether or not he has complete control over the content, that could be an option.

Comment: Edited your answer to reflect that. +1

Comment: much appreciated.